# Check if unix timestamp is within the current month in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have records of questions stored in database. One of the column in question is the `ask_date`.

Example stored in is: `1549923808`.

I want to select records whose `ask_date` is within the current month.

Please how do I calculate that in the `WHERE` clause of my SQL ?

```
//Select questions with the heighest or Top votes or answers this month( current month)
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT Q.*, 
            (SELECT COUNT(Q.question_id) FROM $questions_table Q ) num_of_rows,
          (SELECT COUNT(v.vote_id) FROM $votes_table v WHERE Q.question_id=v.ask_id AND v.vote_type=0 ) votes_down,
          (SELECT COUNT(a.answer_id) FROM $answers_table a WHERE question_id=a.ask_id ) total_answers,
          (SELECT COUNT(v.vote_id) FROM $votes_table v WHERE Q.question_id=v.ask_id ) votes_up,
          CONCAT(m.firstname,' ',m.lastname) author_name,
          m.username u_name FROM $questions_table Q 
          LEFT JOIN $main_table m ON Q.user_id=m.user_id
          WHERE ............

          ) A LEFT JOIN $votes_table V ON A.question_id=V.ask_id 
       GROUP BY A.question_id ORDER BY (
           SELECT COUNT(V.vote_id) vote 
           FROM $votes_table V 
           WHERE V.ask_id=A.question_id
       ) DESC LIMIT  {$maxPageRecords} OFFSET {$offset}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is:

```
where date_format(from_unixtime(ask_date), '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')
```

However, that precludes the use of indexes.  So, this might be better:

```
where ask_date >= unix_timestamp(date(concat_ws('-', year(now()), month(now()), 1)))) and
      ask_date < unix_timestamp(date(concat_ws('-', year(now()), month(now()), 1))) + interval 1 month)
```

Comment: If ask_date is datetime or timestamp, wouldn't leave out `'2019-02-28 23:59:59'` since between's right value would be `'2019-02-28 00:00:00'` ?

Comment: @Sal . . . Don't use `between` with dates or date/times.  Simple comparisons are more accurate.

Comment: My bad, I meant: second operand of second comparison.

Comment: @Sal . . . Not at all.  The `<` does what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

> select records whose `ask_date` is within the current month :

This simple (and index-friendly) expression should get the job done :

```
WHERE ask_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Tuples:
`WHERE (year(ask_date),month(ask_date)) = (year(now()),month(now()))`

Comment: it gives me this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'month(now()) ) A LEFT JOIN votes V ON A.question_id=V.ask_id G' at line 10

Comment: You need to split up the conditions he put there so that you compare the years, then compare the months